# Colocar mais de um input SUBMIT em formulário HTML

Tags: php, formulário, input, button, actions

Tenho na minha página um formulário (form) com uma ação já determinada e um botão input.

```
<form id="educForm1" name="educForm1" action="<?php echo ROOT . 'educacao' ?>/enviaemail" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
    <input id="enviaEmail" name="enviaEmail" type="submit" class="textDescricaoSobre font13" value="Criar Evento" style="cursor: pointer; width: 90px;" />
</form>
```

Ao apertar esse botão enviaEmail, ele deverá gravar os dados do formulário na tabela do banco de dados e automaticamente enviar um e-mail com os dados gravados.

Eu gostaria de colocar um segundo submit, que só fizesse o envio do e-mail e que não gravasse no banco. O primeiro submit faria só a gravação dos dados, mas não deverá fazer o refresh da página no action (action=php echo ROOT . 'educacao' /enviaemail).

O que eu poderia fazer? Mudar a ação do action? Colocar button ou invés de input? Estou aberto à sugestões.

Comment: voce teria que tratar os envios via javascript, fazendo cada botao chamar um funcao

Comment: Pode usar o mesmo submit o com um checkbox indicando se deve ou não gravar no banco as informações.

Answer (score 1):

Use o checkbox ou um select(sim/não) no form para indicar se o registro deve ou não ser salvo no banco.

Como enviar email é obrigatório, divida o código em pelo menos duas funções uma que grava no banco e outra que faz o envio do email, dessa forma o fluxo principal do programa fica bem simples.

Algo como:

```
<?php
   $msg = enviarEmail($dadosForm); //retorna uma string sucesso ou falha.
   if($_POST['insert'] == 'sim'){
      gravarNoBanco($dadosForm);
   }

   echo $msg;
```

Answer (score -2):

É possível sim, basta fazer varios  botões submit com o mesmo nome e valores diferentes, capturar as informações do post para uma só pagina e lá , faça a filtragem com if dessa forma :

....

```
    <<form name="Cadastro" method="post" action="cadastro.php">
        <input type="submit" id="f_submit" name="Fm_submit" value="Lista">
        <input type="submit" id="f_submit" name="Fm_submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="submit" id="f_submit" name="Fm_submit" value="Altera">
        <input type="submit" id="f_submit" name="Fm_submit" value="Apaga">
        <input type="reset" id="f_reset" name="Fm_resset" value="Reset">
```

....

e para filtara no cadastro.php use :

```
$R_nome=$_POST["Fm_nome"];
$R_telefone=$_POST["Fm_telefone"];
$R_botao=$_POST["Fm_submit"];
$R_registro=$_POST["Fm_registro"];
if ($R_botao == "Submit") {$b1->gravaRegistro($db1,$p1->getDados());}
if ($R_botao == "Lista") {$b1->listaTabela($db1);}
if ($R_botao == "Apaga") {$b1->apagaRegistro($db1,$R_registro);}
if ($R_botao == "Altera") {$b1->alteraRegistro($db1,$p1->getDados());}
```